# Macbook Air El Capitan constant message about iCloud

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, system-settings

My Macbook Air OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 gives me a notification about every 5 minutes that says `Finish changing your password`. I get directed to the iCloud settings when I press the `details`button on the notification. When System Preferences pops up a prompt also comes with it that says `iCloud Preferences wants to make changes to your account. Type your password to allow this.`. Nothing happens after I enter my password besides the prompt disappearing. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

PIA vpn blocked the connection to the Apple servers. I disconnected from the VPN and it worked